# No visual appearing

Tags: java, jframe

I am working on a java game for class where we implement a game of nim.  I thought that I was nearing completion but when I ran the program, nothing appears. It just says build successful and quits. I never get to see the game or play it.  Below is my code for the application.

```
package Nim;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Nim extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    // Number of stickSpace that is needed for the sticks;
    int rowspace = 3;

    // Buttons for the human to click to take turns playing witht the computer.
    private JButton humanMove,
                    computerMove;

    // whatRow = what row the user would like to remove from
    // howMany = how many sticks to take from each row
    private JComboBox whatRow,
                      howMany;

    // Creates an array of JTextFields with the rowspace as a size.
    private JTextField[] stickSpace = new JTextField[rowspace];

    // Creates the game;
    private Nimgame nimgame;

    public void Nim(){

        //As requireed, we use a loop to fill the array.
       for(int i=0; i<rowspace ;i++){
            stickSpace[i] = new JTextField(5);
        }


       // Creates pulldown menus for the user to select the whatRow s/he 
       // wants to choose from, and another for howMany s/he wants to take.
        whatRow = new JComboBox();
        howMany = new JComboBox();

        // Add the options to the pulldown menus so the player can choose.
        // 0-2 because the array index starts at 0. 1-3 for the amount of sticks.

        for(int p=0; p<=3; p++){
            if(p<3){
               whatRow.addItem(p); 
            }
            if(p>0){
                howMany.addItem(p);
            }
        }

        // Adds the text "Human Turn" and "CPU Turn" to the buttons used for turns.
        humanMove = new JButton("Human Turn");
        computerMove = new JButton("CPU Turn");

        // Adds a listener to the buttons to signal the game its time to act.
        humanMove.addActionListener(this);
        computerMove.addActionListener(this);

        // Creates a gridlayout (3,2) with 3 rows and two columns.
        JPanel gridpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

        // Labels the rows so the player knows it starts at row Zero - Three.
        gridpanel.add(new JLabel("Row Zero", JLabel.LEFT));
        gridpanel.add(stickSpace[0]);
        gridpanel.add(new JLabel("Row One", JLabel.LEFT));        
        gridpanel.add(stickSpace[1]);
        gridpanel.add(new JLabel("Row Two", JLabel.LEFT));        
        gridpanel.add(stickSpace[2]);

        // Creates another gridlayout this time with 4 rows and 2 columns.
        // This sill be used to add the comboboxes, labels, and buttons.
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2));
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Remove from Row:", JLabel.RIGHT));
        mainPanel.add(whatRow);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("# To Remove:", JLabel.RIGHT));
        mainPanel.add(howMany);
        mainPanel.add(humanMove);
        mainPanel.add(computerMove);

        // This adds the gridpanel and the main panel to the visual
        // application, but they are still not visiable at this moment.
        getContentPane().add(gridpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // This sections sets the title, size, position on screen, sets it visiable,
        // sets the background color, and makes it exit on close of the visual application.
        setTitle("The Game of Nim");
        setSize(300, 250);
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setVisible(true);

        // Creates the actual game to play.
        nimgame = new Nimgame();

        // Prints out the sticks in each row.
        for(int p=0; p<3; p++){
            stickSpace[p].setText(nimgame.addSticks(p));
        }
    }

    // Method to handle when an action lister find an action event
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        // Checks if the humanMove button has been pressed
        if(e.getSource() == humanMove){
            int foo = whatRow.getSelectedIndex();
            int bar = howMany.getSelectedIndex()+1;
            nimgame.stickRemove(foo, bar);

            for(int p=0; p<3; p++){
                stickSpace[p].setText(nimgame.addSticks(p));
            }             
        }

        // Checks if the computerMove button has been pressed.
        if(e.getSource() == computerMove){
            nimgame.computerRandom();
            for(int p=0; p<3; p++){
                stickSpace[p].setText(nimgame.addSticks(p));
            }            
        }

        // Checks to see if the game is over or not.
        if(nimgame.isDone()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over Player Player" + nimgame.whoWon());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Nim NIM = new Nim();
    }
}
```

Any idea why nothing would be showing up? I figured I forgot to setVisible, but that wasn't the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void Nim(){
```

This isn't a constructor, it's a `void` method declaration with an awfully confusing name. As you don't declare a constructor at all, you have an implicit default constructor which is called here:

```
Nim NIM = new Nim();
```

but the default constructor doesn't do what you'd expect, so you don't see anything. To fix this, change the aforementioned method definition to a constructor definition by removing `void`:

```
public Nim() {
```

Comment: Thank you very much kviiri... I have been staring at this for over an hour and it was driving me crazy! I guess sometimes you just need an extra pair of eyes! This solved the problem and will be marked the answer when I can. Thanks again, and have a good day!

Comment: @NerdsRaisedHand, that's very common. Glad to have helped!